# Logging of "direct" iptables rules with firewalld

Tags: linux, iptables, firewalld

I'm using firewalld with the iptables backend. I added "direct" rules for ssh connection limiting:

```bash
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=22/tcp

sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 0 \
  -p tcp --dport 22 \
  -m state --state NEW \
  -m recent --name ssh --set \
  -m comment --comment "limit ssh connections per ip"

sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 1 \
  -p tcp --dport 22 \
  -m state --state NEW \
  -m recent --name ssh --update --seconds 61 --hitcount 4 --rttl \
  -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset \
  -m comment --comment "limit ssh connections per ip"

# ...similarly for ipv6
```

I also want logging for rejects and drops, so I ran

```bash
$ sudo firewall-cmd --set-log-denied all
```

That mostly works - when I check `sudo journalctl --since today --identifier kernel` I see those connections... *but not those rejected by my direct rules.*

On the repo this [was confirmed](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/discussions/1127#discussioncomment-5969921) as expected behaviour, and that I must add more direct rules to log my direct rules:

> You have to use the iptables log extension, e.g. -j LOG. ... Unfortunately you'll need two direct rules as iptables doesn't support -j LOG -j ACCEPT.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. One must add another rule, identical to the REJECT or DROP rule, but which jumps to the "non-terminating" [LOG target](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables).

```bash
$ sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 0 \
  -p tcp --dport 22 \
  -m state --state NEW \
  -m recent --name ssh --set \
  -m comment --comment "limit ssh connections per ip"

$ sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 1 \
  -p tcp --dport 22 \
  -m state --state NEW \
  -m recent --name ssh --update --seconds 61 --hitcount 4 --rttl \
  -m limit --limit "5/min" \
  -j LOG --log-prefix "[REJECT SSH BRUTE FORCE] " --log-level 6 \    # <----------
  -m comment --comment "limit ssh connections per ip"

$ sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 2 \
  -p tcp --dport 22 \
  -m state --state NEW \
  -m recent --name ssh --update --seconds 61 --hitcount 4 --rttl \
  -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset \
  -m comment --comment "limit ssh connections per ip"

# ...similarly for ipv6
```

To view logs for those connections:

```bash
# all rejected and dropped
$ sudo journalctl --grep 'kernel'

# or just just ssh brute force attempts
$ sudo journalctl --grep 'REJECT SSH BRUTE FORCE'
```